# Missing elements? Electron shell filling after argon

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, elements

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configurations_of_the_elements_(data_page)

I am confused about shell fulfillment after argon.

Argon is 2, 8, 8 
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6

why is their not elements hear that are starting to filling the 3d shells

Potassium 2, 8, 8, 1
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6  (why is 3d shell missing?)  4s1(how can this shell fill with nothing underneath it)

calcium 2, 8, 8, 2
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 (again 3d shell missing?)  4s2

scandium 2, 8, 9, 2? 
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d1 4s2(why is their not a element between calcium and scandium that has 
 1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d1 4s1)

titanium 2, 8, 10, 2?
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d2 4s2(why is their not a element between scandium and titanium that has 
 1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d2 4s1)

vanadium 2, 8, 11, 2?
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d3 4s2(why is their not a element that has 
 1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d3 4s1)

chromium 2, 8, 13?, 1?
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d5(why is their not two elements 3d4 4s1 and 3d4 4s1) 4s1(the fact that 4s has only 1 electron in it makes me think it that we are missing elements.)

manganese 2, 8, 13, 2
1s2  2s2  2p6 3s2 3p6 3d5 4s2

what is the pattern that it follows? there are many more in the higher elements that follow this pattern of not filling some shells.

don't shells have to fill up bottom up if not why not? Why do the subatomic partials make it do this?

Comment: Because real electron configurations are more complex then you seem to think?